# Mongoose Model.find().select() If Select is an empty string What's returned?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's assume that we're using a simple schema of this:

```
const phoneRegex = require('./phoneRegex');
const Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;
const PersonSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  phone: {
    type: String,
    regex: phoneRegex,
  },
  Address: {
    street1: String,
    street2: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    zip: String,
  }
});

module.exports = Person = require('mongoose').model('Person', PersonSchema);
```

and I want to have a preset call to mongoose to find a list of people, but I want to have the option to limit what's returned from the database. I understand I can use the `select()` function of the model, but what happens when you provide an empty string? (i.e. `Person.find(options).select('');`)

My predefined function looks like this:

```
//sample options object.
const options = {
  firstName: {
    $regex: '^John',
    $options: 'i',
  },
};
const Person = require('./person');
const fetchAll = (Options, select = '') => {
  return Person.find(Options).select(select);
};
```

I understand that I would want to pass the property name to select it for return, but is an empty selection string the same as "SELECT NONE"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading through [the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) it looks like that all fields will be ignored except for the `_id` field since that's included by default. You're saying `include nothing, exclude everything else`.

I don't currently have a mongoose setup to test this, so it's more of an educated guess.

Comment: That's understandable, and I was thinking that was along these lines. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After testing

```
someDb.find().select("")
```

returns documents with all the fields selected (except the ones with `select: false` in the schema)